# Firebase Test lab -Error creating matrix. One or more of the scenarios you specified to run was not declared in the com.google.test.loops meta-data

Tags: android, firebase, automation, firebase-test-lab

I am new to firebase test lab. I am trying to test simple test run against available apk. I try uploading apk and selected game loop. But I am getting below error. I am using spark plan but I have not run any test yet.

*Error creating matrix. One or more of the scenarios you specified to run was not declared in the com.google.test.loops meta-data tag in your manifest file.*

Comment: Please edit the question with the following: How exactly did you create the matrix?  What exactly is in your manifest file?

Comment: for reference: https://firebase.google.com/docs/test-lab/android/game-loop

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you tried to run a game loop test and specified scenarios (one or multiple scenario numbers) although your `AndroidManifest.xml` does not have any.

To run a game loop test, your manifest needs to contain at least the following Intent that will be used to start the app:

```
<activity android:name=".MyActivity">
   <intent-filter>
       <action android:name="com.google.intent.action.TEST_LOOP"/>
       <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
       <data android:mimeType="application/javascript"/>
   </intent-filter>
   <intent-filter>
      ... (other intent filters here)
   </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

This app will have exactly one scenario "0", the default one. In this case leave the "Scenarios" input field empty:

[image: Scenarios input field]

If you want to have multiple scenarios, add the following to your manifest file:

```
<meta-data
  android:name="com.google.test.loops"
  android:value="5" />
```

Now, you have 5 scenarios and can specify which specifically you want to run, or leave the "Scenarios" field empty to run all.

For more information about the Game Loop test, check out the [official documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/test-lab/android/game-loop).